# Hosting a mvc net core in root and the staging version in a subdirectory using nginx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nginx, .net-core, nginx-config

The idea is to serve a production mvc net core app in website root and the staging version in a subdirectory:

- https://my.website.com (Production)
- https://my.website.com/pre (Staging)

Currently the configuration in nginx is this one:

```
upstream myapp{
        server localhost:5000;
    }

upstream premyapp{
    server localhost:6000;
}

server {
    listen *:80;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen *:443    ssl;
    server_name my.website.com;
    ssl_certificate /home/vhost/ssl/myapp.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/vhost/ssl/myapp-decrypted.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling on; #ensure your cert is capable
    ssl_stapling_verify on; #ensure your cert is capable

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://myapp;
    }

    location /pre {
        proxy_pass  http://premyapp;
    }
}
```

And the configuration in `startup.cs` file has this configuration:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...

        if (env.IsStaging())
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles("/pre");
            app.UsePathBase("/pre");
        }
        else app.UseStaticFiles();

       ...
     }
```

But it doesn't work, the production app doesn't redirect to any controller and the staging app doesn't load the static files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the static files configuration, now is:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...

        if (env.IsStaging())
        {
            app.UsePathBase("/pre");
            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }

       ...
     }
```

And it worked!